# How to handle autoloading with composer by keeping the WordPress naming conventions?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I'm a bit confused because I'm programming a plugin for WordPress by using composer as it's the real way to go.

So I've created a composer file inside my plugin and some other stuff. In the composer file I've added my namespace for autoloading:

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "Johnny\\Lolkick\\": [
      "includes/classes/"
    ]
  }
}
```

Inside my classes folder I've created now a class with the name `class-main.php`. I've decided to take this name because of the [WordPress naming conventions](https://developer.wordpress.org/coding-standards/wordpress-coding-standards/php/#naming-conventions).

The class by itself was named `class Main {`. Inside my base plugin file I've created now a new instance of my class which failed. After changing the file name to `Main.php` it worked.

So in result the WordPress naming convention broke the autoloading of composer. I want to know now how do you handle this problem? How should I keep the naming convention by using composer?

Comment: I'm interested in this as well. It looks like most devs either opt not to use the (_recommended_) WP class filename prefixes or write their own autoloader which does comply. Have you made any progress on this?